# Re-transmission concept in TCP

Tags: routes, tcp

Server sent data to client, but client didn't send ACK for the data . So once RTT completed , Server will resend data to client again .... like that how long it will try to send the data ? What is the maximum time server will try to send the data to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP uses an exponential backoff, meaning that it doubles the time between each unacknowledged retransmission. Once a maximum threshold is reached, the connection is closed. This limit varies from system to system, but is typically between [2 and 9 minutes](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_time.htm).

Answer (score 1):

To provide basic reliability for sent data, each device’s TCP implementation uses a retransmission queue. Each sent segment is placed on the queue and a retransmission timer started for it. When an acknowledgment is received for the data in the segment, it is removed from the retransmission queue. If the timer goes off before an acknowledgment is received the segment is retransmitted and the timer restarted.

Comment: Thanks , What is the timer value ? if you have link for that share with me

Comment: @Bharathi You would like to set the retransmission timer to a value just slightly larger than the round-trip time between the two TCP devices, which is, the typical time it takes to send a segment from a client to a server and the server to send an acknowledgment back to the client (or vice versa). The problem is that there is no such “typical” round-trip time because of differences In connection distance and transient delays.

Comment: so how much time it will try to re-transmit if we didn't receive ACK from client ?

Comment: Sorry for not commenting back on time. I see @Hugh White has already answered.